# Big query inner join with 'like' clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in big query below is an image representation of each\

[image]

What i want is to sum the number of clicks by grouping the appropriate Land URLs. Below is the query I am using but it is not returning any result

```
Select a.quarters as Quarters, sum(b.clicks) as Clicks
from `spreadsheetapi-1147.FlosportsDatabase.GroupByColumnReference` as a 
inner join `spreadsheetapi-1147.FlosportsDatabase.kenshoo` as b 
on lower(a.quarters) like concat('%' , b.land_url , '%' )
group by a.quarters
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switch  `lower(a.quarters)` and `b.land_url` for the LIKE check

```
Select a.quarters as Quarters, sum(b.clicks) as Clicks
from `spreadsheetapi-1147.FlosportsDatabase.GroupByColumnReference` as a 
inner join `spreadsheetapi-1147.FlosportsDatabase.kenshoo` as b 
on b.land_url like concat('%' , lower(a.quarters) , '%' )
group by a.quarters
```